# merge two dataFrame spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want a spark scala method which allows you to merge two dataframes A and B which have the same structure on a join key which can be a list and this in general without writing the column names explicitly

example :

[image]

Comment: Whats the merge logic? I.e. why 'Z' grade is picked over 'A'?

Comment: when a row is in A and B (key) then row A data replace row B data ( update ) 
when a row A (key) is just in A then add row A to B